# How to change focus programmatically in tvOS

Tags: swift, focus, tvos, tvos9.1

I am developing a tvOS app in swift. I am using `UITabBarController` in the app.
My requirement is to hide the tabbar automatic after 10 seconds and focus can move to `AVPlayerViewController` inside the tabbar item.
I tried to override `preferredFocusedView`, but focus cannot move to `AVPlayerViewController`.

```
func updateFocus() {

    self.playerController.view.hidden = false
    self.playerController.view.alpha = 1.0
    self.playerController.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.playerController.view.layer.zPosition = 1.0
    self.preferredFocusedView
    setNeedsFocusUpdate()
    updateFocusIfNeeded()
}

override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {

    return self.playerController.view

}
```

Please suggest me how to move focus programmatically.

Comment: make sure self.playerController.view.superView is focusable

Comment: sorry, I returned self.playerController.view.

Comment: Put a break point and check if that view return true from canBecameFocus, you can do this by executing this command on console [view _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable]

Comment: self.playerController.view is facusable because i swip down to remote then focus move to AVPlayerViewController but not programmatically.

Comment: I have checked self.playerController.view.canBecomeFocused() and its return true but able to executing command on console.

Comment: @C_X can you help me for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225205/how-to-change-keyboard-staterefresh-in-tvos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is `focus` is not in `viewController` at that time instead focus is in `tabBarController`, so what I will suggest you is do something like this, 
Create a `TabBarController` subClass and set class of your tabController in story board to that class, and then in `tabBarController` subClass do something like this.

```
  #import "TabBarViewController.h"

    @interface TabBarViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation TabBarViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.tabBar.alpha = 0;
        // set alpha = 1 back again when you need.
    }

    - (UIView*)preferredFocusedView
    {
// you can also add some if else here
        return [self.selectedViewController preferredFocusedView];// or you can do self.selectedViewController.view if that view is focusable
    }

    @end
```

My selected view controller here is FirstViewController which look like this and its working fine.

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (UIView*)preferredFocusedView
{
    return _button;// return view which you want to make focus able
}
@end
```

Comment: TabBar hidden in particular time but focus still remain on TabBar.

Comment: When I call self.preferredFocusedView in TabBarController class in didSelectViewController method then it's not change focus in AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: you should not call this method itself directly, it will call at start it self, or you should call setNeedUpdateFocus method to re query this method

Comment: preferredFocusedView is deprecated for ios 10. can you please tell me how to use preferredFocusEnvironments instead of that.